# how do i solve ssl error in django collectstatic

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

When I run `collectstatic` in django I get this error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 578, in __init__
    raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")

ValueError: do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-        blocking sockets
```

Does any one know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this code below in one of my files and that was the reason I was getting this issue and am sure its placed in the wrong file.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Comment: I think it is imposible give a good answer to your question because you didn't say you was using gevent. Anyway it helped me. +1